# setDrawingCacheQuality doesn't work in Android?

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, out-of-memory

I tried to get View's caching bitmap, the code is as follows:

```
View cachingView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
cachingView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
cachingView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE,null);
cachingView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_LOW);
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cachingView.getDrawingCache());
LogHelper.i("bitmap size: "+bitmap.getByteCount());
LogHelper.i("bitmap size: "+ BitmapCompat.getAllocationByteCount(bitmap));
```

The print result is :

bitmap size: 14745600

bitmap size: 14745600

Obviously,it is too big. I changed different parameters of **setDrawingCacheQuality** , but the result is the same.

How can I get a smaller bitmap?

Thanks

Comment: Any body can met this problem before, or is there any other method we can get a smaller background cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quality here isn't the quality of the compression like when writing a JPEG.  Its the quality of the alpha blending for transparencies.  So it does work, it just doesn't do what you thought it did.

(As an aside-  Bitmaps in memory are uncompressed, so it doesn't matter what compression quality you use to write them to disk-  in memory they take up the same amount of memory based if they're the same size).